Prevent inserting duplicate entries under READ COMMITTED Isolation
We have a SQL Server table called dbo.Dim_Target. Multiple threads try to INSERT new data into this table in parallel. Each parallel thread first checks for matching data and then only inserts new data (non-matching), using LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Isolation Level is READ COMMITTED.
Problem
On rare occasions, duplicate data is inserted into this table by two different threads a couple of milliseconds apart. According to this post, this issue is expected RC isolation level.
Things I tried

Different isolation levels (RC, Repeatable Read, etc) all could not prevent this problem.
Serializable isolation prevents duplicates, but also causes a lot of deadlock issues.
Unique index is not possible on this large size column

Question
Is there an approach to prevent duplicates from multiple threads?
Sample code to recreate the scenario
1. Preparation
Create target table & two STG tables and load dummy data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Dim_Target
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Dim_Target
(    ID           INT               NOT NULL   IDENTITY(1,1)
   , Code         VARCHAR(3000)     NOT NULL
   , Created_Date DATETIME          NOT NULL   DEFAULT(GETDATE()))
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Dim_Target(Code) SELECT NEWID()    -- some dummy data
GO 10000

--
-- STG table 1
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.STG_Test1
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.STG_Test1
(    ID     INT            NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
   , Code   VARCHAR(3000)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.STG_Test1 (Code) SELECT NEWID()    -- some dummy data
GO 10000
INSERT INTO dbo.STG_Test1 (Code) SELECT 'abc1'     -- this is the duplicate entry that matches STG2 table
GO

--
-- STG table 2
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.STG_Test2
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.STG_Test2
(    ID     INT            NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
   , Code   VARCHAR(3000)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.STG_Test2 (Code) SELECT NEWID()    -- some dummy data
GO 10000
INSERT INTO dbo.STG_Test2 (Code) SELECT 'abc1'     -- this is the duplicate entry that matches STG1 table
GO

--
-- Sample query to check for duplicates
--
SELECT Code, COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.Dim_Target
GROUP BY Code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

2.Thread 1: Try to insert from first parallel thread
Run this below script from one SSMS window. Make sure the WAITFOR time is set the same in both windows.
WAITFOR TIME '16:04:00'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO dbo.Dim_Target (Code) 
    SELECT T.Code
    FROM dbo.STG_Test1 AS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Target AS D
        ON D.Code = T.Code
    WHERE D.Code IS NULL
COMMIT

3. Thread 2: Try to insert from second parallel thread
Run this below script from second SSMS window. Make sure the WAITFOR time is set the same in both windows.
WAITFOR TIME '16:04:00'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO dbo.Dim_Target (Code) 
    SELECT T.Code
    FROM dbo.STG_Test2 AS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Target AS D
        ON D.Code = T.Code
    WHERE D.Code IS NULL
COMMIT

NOTES

When I run this script, the duplicates do not occur every time. They happen once every two or 3 attempts, but they DO happen. The Created_Date column shows that duplicate entries were created just a couple of milliseconds apart.
We have 10 threads running in parallel loading all the Dimension tables, so the duplicates are occurring more frequently.


With a temporary solution working, I want to take time to re-think to make this scalable. All parts of the ETL are processed with multiple threads, except this one step -- which is single threaded (for now). So any ideas would be welcome.

code change
You didn't provide an example of what you did to implement serialzable, but you may have better luck with this:
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO 
        dbo.Dim_Test (Code) 
    SELECT T.Code
    FROM dbo.STG_Test2 AS T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1/0
        FROM dbo.Dim_Test AS D WITH(UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
        WHERE D.Code = T.Code
    );
COMMIT;

You may find the NOT EXISTS pattern generally performs better. It may require a HASH JOIN hint to get the correct plan shape.
An explanation of the required locking hints can be found here: SQL Server UPSERT Patterns and Antipatterns.
schema change
You may be able to hash the contents of the Code column to something that will fit in the key of an index. This will require careful testing on your part to figure out which hash algorithm works best for you, but it will allow you to put a unique constraint on the table.
CREATE TABLE dbo.Dim_Target
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Code varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
    Created_Date datetime NOT NULL
        DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    CodeHashColumn256 AS 
        CONVERT(binary(32), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', Code)) PERSISTED, --PERSISTED is optional, please test
    CodeHashColumn512 AS 
        CONVERT(binary(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', Code)) PERSISTED --PERSISTED is optional, please test
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 
    HashComparisonTable_HashedColumn256
ON dbo.Dim_Target
    (CodeHashColumn256, ID);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 
    HashComparisonTable_HashedColumn512
ON dbo.Dim_Target
    (CodeHashColumn512, ID);

This may also be a good use case for the IGNORE_DUP_KEY index option if you wish to just discard attempted duplicate rows without raising an error.

Looks like the comment I added after trying your idea was removed. Hmm... I may be breaking etiquette rules with my comments

Instead of a unique constraint/index on [Code], could you create it on a computed hash of [Code] instead?
As you've found a unique constraint on [Code] gives a warning and large updates fail:-
ALTER TABLE dbo.Dim_Target ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_DIM_TARGET_CODE UNIQUE (Code);

Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'UQ_DIM_TARGET_CODE' has maximum length of 3000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

UPDATE dbo.Dim_Target 
SET Code =  REPLICATE('A', 3000) 
WHERE ID = 1;

Msg 1946, Level 16, State 3, Line 20
Operation failed. The index entry of length 3000 bytes for the index 'UQ_DIM_TARGET_CODE' exceeds the maximum length of 1700 bytes for nonclustered indexes.

/* Clean-up */
ALTER TABLE dbo.Dim_Target DROP CONSTRAINT UQ_DIM_TARGET_CODE;

But a unique constraint on a hash of [Code] is fine despite the warning, the column will only ever be 256-bits (32-bytes) long:-
ALTER TABLE dbo.Dim_Target ADD CodeHash AS HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', Code) PERSISTED CONSTRAINT UQ_DIM_TARGET_CODEHASH UNIQUE;

Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'UQ_DIM_TARGET_CODEHASH' has maximum length of 8000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

UPDATE dbo.Dim_Target 
SET Code =  REPLICATE('B', 3000) 
WHERE ID = 2;

(1 row affected)

You could either trap a uniqueness violation on INSERT, or amend your INSERTs to check for [CodeHash] existence.
Amending the INSERTs to check for the [CodeHash] also has the advantage of utilising the unique index instead of scanning the destination table for [Code].
INSERT INTO dbo.Dim_Target (Code) 
SELECT T.Code
FROM dbo.STG_Test1 AS T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM dbo.Dim_Target AS D 
   WHERE D.CodeHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', T.Code))

Furthermore, pre-calculation of [CodeHash] could similarly be moved into the Staging table(s) using a computed column.
INSERT INTO dbo.Dim_Target (Code) 
SELECT T.Code
FROM dbo.STG_Test1 AS T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM dbo.Dim_Target AS D 
   WHERE D.CodeHash = T.CodeHash)


After thinking this through and playing with it a bit more, I see that using codehash in the INSERT statement does not prevent the possibility of a duplicate. While, having a UNIQUE index on the CodeHash column could stop the duplicate entries from entering the table.

Without the unique index, consider this. When two parallel threads read the target table (dbo.Dim_Target) and see that the new entry (let's say 'abc') does not exist in the dbo.Dim_Target table. So, both the threads attempt to INSERT it. Hence the duplicate entry called 'abc'. If both the threads are reading the able at the same time, the value 'abc' does not exist in the table. So, they attempt INSERT -- which results in duplicates. Using codehash does not prevent this as 'codehash' subquery says that the new entry 'abc' does not exist in the table.

As Erik Darling & Rob Dalzell said in their answers, adding a column to store hash of Code column and building a unique index on the hash column will prevent insertion of duplicate rows. Using this hash column in comparison operations will give better performance.
It will throw a duplicate key error in one thread, when two threads try to insert the same hash code. It's OK, because code from the other thread has already been inserted and committed. All other rows contained in the error thread will be rollback this time. But they will be reinserted next time.
Another suggestion is split the dataset from source (STG_Test) into a few parts. This will decrease the chances of inserting the same code from multiple sources -- more rows, more duplicate data. It will also reduce memory usage. The negative side of this operation is bad performance; committing a transaction has a heavy cost. So carefully test with different sizes of dataset, if you choose this method.
I built a sample based on those thoughts:
1. Create Target table with unique index
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Dim_Target
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Dim_Target
    (    ID           INT               NOT NULL   IDENTITY(1,1)
       , Code         VARCHAR(3000)     NOT NULL
       , Created_Date DATETIME          NOT NULL   DEFAULT(GETDATE())
       , CodeHash AS CONVERT(binary(32), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', Code)) PERSISTED
    );
    GO
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_Dim_Target_Hashcode ON dbo.Dim_Target (CodeHash) ;
    GO

2. Insert rows piece by piece
    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO dbo.Dim_Target (Code) 
            SELECT TOP 2000 T.Code      --This cuts source to 6 parts, last part has 1 row
            FROM dbo.STG_Test1 AS T
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Target AS D
                ON D.CodeHash = CONVERT(binary(32), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', T.Code)) 
            WHERE D.CodeHash IS NULL
            ORDER BY T.ID
            IF(@@ROWCOUNT=0) 
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION
                BREAK
            END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT CONCAT('ERROR: ', ERROR_MESSAGE())--can be removed
            IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END

